# Matlab: Deleting elements from a vector

Tags: matlab, loops

I am not sure why the code below doesn't work. I'm basically trying to get rid of elements in `probofdetectionanddelamprop` that are equal to 1 or are less than 10e-12, which means that the size of `probofdetectionanddelamprop` is changing dynamically. I therefore added a while loop to check when `i` equals the new `size(probofdetectionanddelamprop)`, but this does not appear to be working.

```
while i ~= numel(probofdetectionanddelamprop)
for i = 1:no_iterations % Clearly, no_iterations is > numel(probofdetectionanddelamprop)
    if (probofdetectionanddelamprop(i) <=10e-12 || probofdetectionanddelamprop(i) == 1)
        probofdetectionanddelamprop(i) = [];     
    end
end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
probofdetectionanddelamprop(probofdetectionanddelamprop < 1e-11 | probofdetectionanddelamprop == 1) = [];
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of tracking which of the elements of `probofdetectionanddelamprop` are deleted?

Comment: The statement `probofdetectionanddelamprop < 1e-11` and `probofdetectionanddelamprop == 1` are both logical arrays. The places when they are equal to 1 means that element is chosen. If you want an integer array of indices chosen, you can say `find(probofdetectionanddelamprop < 1e-11 | probofdetectionanddelamprop == 1)`